# Use separation of variables to solve BVP with mixed boundary conditions.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

Use separation of variables to solve the following BVP with mixed boundary conditions;
$$
\begin{cases}
 u_t = u_{xx} &x\in (0,l), t>0 \\
 u(0,t) = T_0 & t>0 \\
 u_x(l,t) = 0 & t>0 \\
 u(x, 0) = T_1 &x\in(0,l)
\end{cases}
$$
where $T_0$ and $T_1$ are constants. In particular solve the above for $T_0 = 1, T_1=5$.

I tried to do it and got stuck. In particular, the condition $T_0 \neq T_1$ threw me of. This problem is in a section on how to solve boundary value problems by separation of variables and using Fourier series.

Comment: In this case, since they are just constants, you should have no problem carrying out SepVar, The only thing that shows up is a slightly different boundary problem when you get to the system of ODE's. Where exactly do you get stuck?

Comment: In addition to DaveNines question, I would say edit your post to include what you have tried so others can see where you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separation of variables problems such as this require homogeneous endpoint conditions, which is usually achieved by a substitution in a case like this.
$$
          v(x,t)=u(x,t)-T_0.
$$
The new equation for $v$ is
$$
               v_t = v_{xx} \\
               v(0,t)=u(0,t)-T_0=0 \\
               v_{x}(l,t)=u_{x}(l,t)=0 \\
               v(x,0)=u(x,0)-T_0=T_1-T_0.
$$
Now when you separate $v(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, the ODE in $x$ becomes
$$
                    \frac{X''}{X}=\lambda,\;\; X(0)=0,\; X'(l)=0.
$$
The eigenfunctions are
$$
                    \sin(\pi x/2l), \sin(3\pi x/2l),\sin(5\pi x/2l),\cdots.
$$
with corresponding eigenvalues $(2n+1)^2\pi^2/4l^2$. These are automatically orthogonal, and you have to expand $v(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_nX_n(x)T_n(t)$ in such a way that $v(x,0)=T_1-T_0$, which leads to a Fourier series problem in the orthogonal eigenfunctions $X_n$, and gives the constants $C_n$.